# Cite equation using tables notes

Tags: tablenotes

I'm trying to find a way to cite my equation as a note under the table here the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
  \captionsetup{font=bf}
  \newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\CEOPC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_PC}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\Boardind}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Board\_ind}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\OP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OP}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\OF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OF}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\Zscore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Z\_Score}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\NPLs}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPLs}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\NPL}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPL}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\LnZ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ln\_Z}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\LnZscore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LnZ\_score}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LTS}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LTS}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\EA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EA}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LT}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LT}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\PF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape PF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\EF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LV}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LGI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LGI}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\AGI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape AGI}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\DD}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape DD}}\nolimits}




 \begin{document}

\\ we use the following model

 \begin{equation}
   \Risk_{i,t} = c + &\alpha \Risk_{i,t-1} + \beta_{1}\CEOPC_{i,t} + \beta_{2}\Boardind_{i,t} + 
 \beta_{k}\Controls_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}\label{eq:1}
  \end{equation}

\\ \Cref{tab2} presents the regression results :

   \begin{table}[h]  
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.3, 
            table-number-alignment=center, 
             table-space-text-pre =(, 
             table-space-text-post=$^{***}$, 
            table-align-text-pre=false, 
           table-align-text-post=false}
    \centering          
   \caption{Risk}
   \label{tab2}
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{S}}
   \toprule
    \thead{Variable} & {\thead{\NPLs}} & {\thead{\LnZscore}} \\
   \midrule
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Constant} & -0.1064\tc{***} & 5.0727\tc{***} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}         & {(}-3.42{)} & {(}5.35{)} \\    
  \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$\NPL$_{i,t-1}$$} & 0.021\tc{***}   & \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}              & {(}5.73{)}  & \\
   \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LnZ$_{it-1}$$} &     &  0.1452\tc{***} \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}               &     & {(}5.83{)} \\
 \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\CEOPC$_{it}$$} & 6.4521\tc{***}   & 0.0124 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                 & {(}11.14{)} & {(}1.12{)} \\  
 \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\Boardind$} & -0.1452\tc{**}    & -0.1245\tc{***}  \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             & {(}-2.11{)} & {(}-8.25{)} \\              
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OF$} & -0.0103\tc{***}  & 0.0345\tc{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}         & {(}-2.45{)} & {(}2.33{)} \\              
  \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OP$} & -0.1445\tc{*}    & 0.1478\tc{*} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}         & {(}-1.91{)} & {(}1.90{)} \\            
  \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LTS$} & 0.1019\tc{**}    &-0.2645\tc{***} \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}     & {(}2.45{)} & {(}-3.47{)} \\       
 \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\EA$} & 0.2114 & 0.4789 \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}1.03{)} & {(}0.10{)} \\                
 \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LT$} & -0.1478\tc{*} & -0.2010\\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-0.45{)} & {(}-0.14{)} \\
 \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\PF$} & -0.5240\tc{*} & -0.0520 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-3.06{)} & {(}-1.24{)} \\                   
 \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\EF$} & 0.0120 & -1.2322\tc{***} \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}4.20{)} & {(}-2.20{)} \\
\addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LV$} & -0.1478\tc{***} &  \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-11.02{)} &  \\ 
 \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LGI$} & 0.1247 &  \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}0.2010{)} &  \\    
  \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\AGI$} &  & 0.0012\tc{***} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & {(}0.1478{)} \\  
 \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\DD$} &  & 0.14789 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & {(}0.01236{)} \\    
  \midrule
    Year dummy & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} \\
        \addlinespace
       \multirow{2}[1]{*}{R$^2$} &   -1.156 &  -2.452 \\
       \addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Adjusted R$^2$} &   0.652 & 1.562 \\
    \addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Sargan test} & 12.02\tc{***} &41.02\tc{***} \\
    \addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
\footnotesize\smallskip
   \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table reports SGMM estimation results of $\label{eq:1}$ where non-performing loans to total loans (\NPL), and Z-score (\LnZ) are the endogenous variables for bank $i$ and year $t$. The $\NPL$_{i,t-1}$ and $\LnZ$_{it-1}$ are lagged dependent variables. $\OP$ and $\OF$ is the independent PRIVATE (DUMMY), FOREIGN (DUMMY), passive shareholding (\PF), minority active shareholding (\EF) and active shareholding (\LTS) are the main explanatory ownership variables. Bank size (\LTS), corporate governance (\EA), financial leverage (\LT) are bank level control variables; and growth of product (\LGI), rate of inflation (\AGI) are two macro-economic control variables. T-statistics are between parentheses; \enspace *** $p < 0.01$; \enspace ** $p < 0.05$;\enspace * $p < 0.10$. The Sargan test justifies the validity of the over identifying restrictions.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a start: Remove the two instances of `\\ ` that are outside of the table. Also remove the `&` in the equation. Please add the definition of `\Controls`.

Comment: `\NPLs` and `\LnZscore` can only be used in math mode, you you can't use them in the table headers like you currently try to do. Something like `\thead{Variable} & {\thead{\(\NPLs\)}} & {\thead{\(\LnZscore\)}}` should at least remove this error message. The same also applies to all the commands in your table note (such as `\LTS`, `\AGI`,...) Please fix that.

Comment: What is `$\label{eq:1}$ ` supposed to do in the table notes? Probably you wanted to use `\ref{eq:1}` instead?

Comment: @leandriis Yes I  want to reference EQ1

Comment: How is the `\tc` command defined? Is it the definition Zarko showed you here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553967/134144?

Comment: \newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

Comment: `$\NPL$_{i,t-1}$$` is not correct. Use `$\NPL_{i,t-1}$` or even better: `\(\NPL_{i,t-1}\)`) instead and correct all other occurences of similar code.

Comment: Once you have done all these corrections, your code should sompile without any error message. If that's the case take a look at the output and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: The vertical alignment in the lower part of your table seems to be a bit off. Does "Adjusted R2" belong to " 0.652 & 1.562"?

Comment: @leandriis yes 0.652 & 1.562 refers to Adjusted R2, by the way, I still don't' get with  \thead{Variable} a nice note under the table :(

Comment: Currently, all of my comments and suggestions were just related to the various errors in your code. Let's fix them first and make your code compilable before looking at the tablenote issue. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.  So, let's start with getting rid of all error messages first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have done the following changes in comparison to the original code:

- commented out duplicate package. Please only load packages once especially, avoid conflicting package options. I have also correctly placed `hyperref` at the end of the preamble.
- removed the `&` in the equation and the occurences of `\\`  outside of the table
- added the missing definitions of `tc` according to the comments and of `\Controls` according to my guess
- added math-mode where needed and removed redundant `$`s
- removed `\multirow` commands in the lower part of the table in order to fix the horizontal alignment
- corrected the `table-format` option of `sisetup` according to the numbers that are present in the table
- removed redundant `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`
- replaced the wrong `$\label{eq:1}$` in the notes part with `\cref{eq:1}`.

Additionally to the above mentioned changes, I would also suggest to use a simple `tabular` for your table. Forcing the table wo be as wide as the textwidth introduces a lot of white space and makes the table harder to read. I also replaced the `threeparttalbe`'s tablenotes environment with a simple `minipage` in order to make sure the notes part below the table stays as wide as the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
%\usepackage{booktabs} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
%\usepackage{multirow} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{placeins}
%\usepackage{varioref} % <--- moved to the end of the preamble. Mind the correct load order
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
%\usepackage{caption} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{xparse}    
%\usepackage{hyperref} % <--- moved to the end of the preamble. Mind the correct load order
%\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % <--- moved to the end of the preamble. Mind the correct load order
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
%\usepackage{booktabs}%<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{booktabs, makecell} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
%\usepackage{siunitx} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage{booktabs, makecell} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, makecell, caption} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage{threeparttable} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!
%\usepackage{siunitx} %<-- removed. don't load packages more than once!


\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\captionsetup{font=bf}


\newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_PC}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\Boardind}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Board\_ind}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\OP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OP}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\OF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\Zscore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Z\_Score}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\NPLs}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPLs}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\NPL}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPL}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LnZ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ln\_Z}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LnZscore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LnZ\_score}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LTS}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LTS}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\EA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EA}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LT}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LT}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\PF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape PF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\EF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LV}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LGI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LGI}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\AGI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape AGI}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\DD}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape DD}}\nolimits}

\newcommand{\Controls}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Controls}}\nolimits}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\begin{document}

we use the following model

\begin{equation}
   \Risk_{i,t} = c + \alpha \Risk_{i,t-1} + \beta_{1}\CEOPC_{i,t} + \beta_{2}\Boardind_{i,t} + 
 \beta_{k}\Controls_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\Cref{tab2} presents the regression results :

\begin{table}[ht]  
\sisetup{table-format=-2.5,  % corrected values with respect to the numbers in your table
         table-number-alignment=center, 
         table-space-text-pre =(, 
         table-space-text-post=$^{***}$, 
         table-align-text-pre=false, 
         table-align-text-post=false}
\centering          
\caption{Risk}
\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S}}
\toprule
\thead{Variable} & {\thead{$\NPLs$}} & {\thead{$\LnZscore$}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Constant}       & -0.1064\tc{***} & 5.0727\tc{***} \\
                                   & {(}-3.42{)}     & {(}5.35{)} \\    
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{$\NPL_{i,t-1}$} & 0.021\tc{***}   & \\
                                   & {(}5.73{)}      & \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LnZ_{it-1}$}  &                 &  0.1452\tc{***} \\
                                   &                 & {(}5.83{)} \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\CEOPC_{it}$}  & 6.4521\tc{***}  & 0.0124 \\
                                   & {(}11.14{)}     & {(}1.12{)} \\  
\addlinespace 
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\Boardind$}    & -0.1452\tc{**}  & -0.1245\tc{***}  \\
                                   & {(}-2.11{)}     & {(}-8.25{)} \\              
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OF$}          & -0.0103\tc{***} & 0.0345\tc{**} \\
                                   & {(}-2.45{)}     & {(}2.33{)} \\              
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OP$}          & -0.1445\tc{*}   & 0.1478\tc{*} \\
                                   & {(}-1.91{)}     & {(}1.90{)} \\            
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LTS$}         & 0.1019\tc{**}   &-0.2645\tc{***} \\
                                   & {(}2.45{)}      & {(}-3.47{)} \\       
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\EA$}          & 0.2114          & 0.4789 \\
                                   & {(}1.03{)}      & {(}0.10{)} \\                
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LT$}          & -0.1478\tc{*}   & -0.2010\\
                                   & {(}-0.45{)}     & {(}-0.14{)} \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\PF$}          & -0.5240\tc{*}   & -0.0520 \\
                                   & {(}-3.06{)}     & {(}-1.24{)} \\                   
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\EF$}          & 0.0120          & -1.2322\tc{***} \\
                                   & {(}4.20{)}      & {(}-2.20{)} \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LV$}          & -0.1478\tc{***} &  \\
                                   & {(}-11.02{)}    &  \\ 
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LGI$}         & 0.1247          &  \\
                                   & {(}0.2010{)}    &  \\    
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\AGI$}         &                 & 0.0012\tc{***} \\
                                   &                 & {(}0.1478{)} \\  
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\DD$}          &                 & 0.14789 \\
                                   &                 & {(}0.01236{)} \\    
\midrule
Year dummy                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} \\
R$^2$                              &   -1.156        &  -2.452 \\
Adjusted R$^2$                     &   0.652         & 1.562 \\
Sargan test                        & 12.02\tc{***}   & 41.02\tc{***} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\small
\textit{Note:} This table reports SGMM estimation results of \cref{eq:1} where non-performing loans to total loans ($\NPL$), and Z-score ($\LnZ$) are the endogenous variables for bank $i$ and year $t$. The $\NPL_{i,t-1}$ and $\LnZ_{it-1}$ are lagged dependent variables. $\OP$ and $\OF$ is the independent PRIVATE (DUMMY), FOREIGN (DUMMY), passive shareholding ($\PF$), minority active shareholding ($\EF$) and active shareholding ($\LTS$) are the main explanatory ownership variables. Bank size ($\LTS$), corporate governance ($\EA$), financial leverage ($\LT$) are bank level control variables; and growth of product ($\LGI$), rate of inflation ($\AGI$) are two macro-economic control variables. T-statistics are between parentheses; \enspace *** $p < 0.01$; \enspace ** $p < 0.05$;\enspace * $p < 0.10$. The Sargan test justifies the validity of the over identifying restrictions.
 \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```